# Configure Training job using Ground Truth and BlazingText in Amazon Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to configure a Training-Job with BlazingText algorithm in Amazon Sagemaker using its console. I have an manifest file as follows:

```
{"source":"Text1","GroundtruthTryVideo":2,"GroundtruthTryVideo-metadata": 
{"confidence":0.66,"job-name":"labeling-job/groundtruthtryvideo","class-name":"TrackingToProspecting","human-annotated":"yes","creation-date":"2018-12-27T00:37:23.894062","type":"groundtruth/text-classification"}}
{"source":"Text2","GroundtruthTryVideo":1,"GroundtruthTryVideo-metadata": 
{"confidence":0.66,"job-name":"labeling-job/groundtruthtryvideo","class-name":"FirstDateProspecting","human-annotated":"yes","creation-date":"2018-12-27T00:37:23.894043","type":"groundtruth/text-classification"}}
{"source":"Text3","GroundtruthTryVideo":1,"GroundtruthTryVideo-metadata": 
{"confidence":0.9,"job-name":"labeling-job/groundtruthtryvideo","class-name":"FirstDateProspecting","human-annotated":"yes","creation-date":"2018-12-27T00:38:26.377216","type":"groundtruth/text-classification"}}
```

When I try to create the trainingjob using this manifest, I get Always troubles with the result, my configurations are:

Algorithm source:

Amazon SageMaker built-in algorithm (BlazingText)

Channels:

- S3 data type: ManifestFile
- S3 data distribution type: FullyReplicated
- S3 location: Path to ManifestFile (In S3 Bucket)

I've tried to use `augmentedManifestFile` and `Pipe` as input mode instead of `ManifestFile` and `File` input but I have the same result, I can't complete the training job successfully.

Could anybody help me in configuring correctly the console? Thanks.

Comment: When you choose `AugmentedManifestFile`, you need to specify 2 attribute names. Are you doing that? In this example, it would be `source` and `GroundtruthTryVideo-metadata`.

Comment: I've tried to use the two attribute names, however, I always get the same trouble, the result is:

Comment: I've tried to use the two attribute names, however, I always get the same trouble, the result is:  `ClientError: Only the supervised text classification mode supports PIPE mode with Augmented Manifest file.` Even though I'm using `Pipe` and `Supervised` options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an engineer at AWS, and want to chime in to offer some additional help. I would echo the suggestion above to check the `AttributeNames` parameter in your training job request definition. I would also like to draw your attention to a few examples that might help illustrate the use of this feature.

1. This sample Jupiter notebook shows how to use an Augmented Manifest to train an object detection model. I understand that this use case is slightly different than your own (object detection vs text classification), but the concepts are similar. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/ground_truth_labeling_jobs/object_detection_augmented_manifest_training/object_detection_augmented_manifest_training.ipynb
2. This full, end-to-end example of a labeling job also contains some content regarding Augmented Manifests that might be useful. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/ground_truth_labeling_jobs/object_detection_augmented_manifest_training/object_detection_augmented_manifest_training.ipynb
3. This blog posts provides another example of training a model with an augmented manifest, and does so via the AWS console. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/easily-train-models-using-datasets-labeled-by-amazon-sagemaker-ground-truth/
4. Lastly, the documentation on Augmented Manifests might also be valuable. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/augmented-manifest.html#augmented-manifest-console

Finally, please remember that we at AWS can be contacted at https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/.